# Flink handling Kafka messages with parsing error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

I have some Kafka messages of type InputIoTMessage coming in from Kafka and consumed through FlinkKafkaConsumer as below. I want to add an error field in InputIoTMessage class if there is a NoSuchFieldException. Also, Is this the best practice to handle this types of scenario or we have something more elegant in Java 8 e.g. using Option or Future?

```
    String inputTopic = "sensors";
    String outputTopic = "sensors_out";
    String consumerGroup = "baeldung";
    String address = "kafka:9092"; 

    StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    FlinkKafkaConsumer011<InputIoTMessage> flinkKafkaConsumer = createIoTConsumerForTopic(inputTopic, address, consumerGroup);
    flinkKafkaConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
    

    DataStream<InputIoTMessage> stringInputStream = environment.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);
    System.out.println("IoT Message received :: " );
    
    stringInputStream
    .filter((event) -> {
        if(event.has("jsonParseError")) {
            LOG.warn("JsonParseException was handled: " + event.get("jsonParseError").asText());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
    .print();
```

InputIoTMessage.java (has method to check if field exists)

```
public boolean has(String fieldName) {
    boolean isExists;
    try {
        isExists = fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.getClass().getField(fieldName).getName());
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        Field[] fieldArr = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                
        //Question: how to add "jsonParseError" field to the object here ?
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter function does not modify the input records, maybe you can implement the flatMap function, after modifying the record, output through out.collect

```
    stringInputStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<InputIoTMessage, InputIoTMessage>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(InputIoTMessage input, Collector<InputIoTMessage> out) {
            if (!input.has("jsonParseError")) {
                InputIoTMessage output = xxxxx;
                out.collect(output);
            }
        }
    });
```